# Understanding PARTITION BY and is there a better way to get the same answer?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following snippet from a query that I'm rebuilding:

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ACCOUNT_ID, LETTER_TYPE, LETTER_DATE, LETTER_ID
           FROM (SELECT T1.ACCOUNT_ID, T2.LETTER_TYPE, T1.LETTER_DATE, T1.LETTER_ID,
                 DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY T1.ACCOUNT_ID, T2.LETTER_TYPE
                                    ORDER BY T1.LETTER_DATE DESC) AS RANK1
                 FROM tableOne T1
                 INNER JOIN tableTwo T2 ON T1.LETTER_ID = T2.LETTERID)
           WHERE RANK1 = 1)
```

I haven't really dealt with `DENSE_RANK()` or `PARTITION BY` before but based on my research this case would translate to "Order this group of records by ACCOUND_ID and LETTER_DATE descending) AND then the outer SELECT grabs only the ones where RANK = 1. So it's basically trying to find the most recent LETTER_ID sent for each account.

My question is: **A.** Is that an accurate translation? and **B.** Is there a way to rewrite/restructure this query so that it doesn't have to be nested like this?

What I mean in **B.** is that it returns all of the LETTER_IDs first and is then filtered to `WHERE RANK1 = 1`. Returning all of those records only to discard them immediately afterward seems like somewhat of a waste

Comment: You can't filter using windowed functions, so generally you do need to have it in a subquery or drop the results into a table before you can filter on the field.

Comment: re: (B) - in SQL, you tell the system *what* you want. It works out *how* to efficiently obtain that data. Depending on how smart the optimizer is, it may already know only to return the `RANK1 = 1` rows from the inner query. Unless there's a proven performance issue, generally you should trust the optimizer to do the right thing.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I have no problem trusting the optimizer to do it's thing. I'm just learning these functions and trying to get a grasp on their inner workings/best practices. I had no idea the optimizer would even consider not returning the results I never intend to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rewrite the query to be something like this:

```
LEFT JOIN (select t1.account_id, t2.letter_type, MAX(t1.letter_date) as MaxDate
           from tableOne t1 join tableTwo t2 on T1.LETTER_ID = T2.LETTERID
          ) maxt left outer join
          (select T1.ACCOUNT_ID, T2.LETTER_TYPE, T1.LETTER_DATE, T1.LETTER_ID
           from tableOne t1 join tableTwo t2 on T1.LETTER_ID = T2.LETTERID
          ) t
          on t.account_id = tmax.account_id and t.letter_type = tmax.letter_type and
             t.letter_date = tmax.maxdate
```

However, I advise you that the window/analytic functions are *very* powerful additions to SQL, so you should learn how to use them.

One question in this case, though.  If there are multiple letters on the most recent letter_date, then your query (and this one too) will return all the letters.  Perhaps your intention is to return only one of them.  In that case, you can use `row_number()` instead of `dense_rank()`.

Comment: Nevermind previous comment, I reread and understand what you meant now. That's a good point, I'm not sure what the intention is so I'll have to test some more and see if I can figure it out.